# GLSL Standalone Shader Compiler

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I've been looking for standalone shader compiler in Linux - for example, to compile source code from shadertoy.com. I found some - like shadertoy-master or shadertoy-view-master repositories on github, but they don't work. Is there any way to compile shader source code as easily as c++ code?

Comment: what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Take a look: [Shader Compilation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation)

Comment: [oh hey](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/)

Comment: Compile to what? Oh I dunno, maybe a standalone animation to watch?

Comment: @CheshireCat That's a bit more involved than just "compiling a shader". You would need to create a window and OpenGL context, as well as draw a scene using the fragment shader (though shadertoy just draws a quad over the whole area).

Answer (score 3):

ShaderToy.com, as far as I can tell, uses GLSL. You don't compile GLSL shaders offline; you give the source to OpenGL at runtime.

Shaders need to run on a wide variety of devices and GPUs. nVidia GPUs are unlikely to use the same machine code as AMD GPUs, or Intel Integrated Graphics, or the CPU if software rendering is being used. The only way to ensure that the shader can be ran is by giving the shader source to the implementation at runtime and letting it compile the shader to whatever format it needs.

Newer versions of OpenGL include [the ability to precompile shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation), to speed up loading. The compiled code is implementation specific, though, and thus not cross-platform. Even if you try to load the compiled shader on the same computer you compiled it on, there's still no guarantee it will work, so you still need to bundle the GLSL source code.

Comment: Note that Khronos is on the way of specifying a (rather high level) shader AST format, that would allow to "compile" shaders into something that spares the OpenGL driver from parsing (which is error prone – in fact I already found several bugs in NVidia's GLSL shader parser related to parsing number literals if a non-standard locale is loaded). Anyway, this AST is just there to decouple the language syntax from the driver implementation. So you'd have one standard reference parser-AST generator which very good diagnostics for everything that can be caught statically.

Comment: @datenwolf In other words, as so often they're working on something that's been part of Direct3D for ages.

Comment: @PaulK: The downside to the Direct3D approach is, that it doesn't allow for a as rapid evolution of the API as it is possible for OpenGL. Also having the compiler being part of the driver/OpenGL implementation allows the vendor to add vendor specific extensions, which allow developers to experiment with new features and give feedback before they are turned into core API features.

Comment: @datenwolf  the shader AST format you were talking about then, is it now called [SPIR-V](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/1.0/SPIRV.html#_a_id_capabilities_a_language_capabilities)?

Comment: @Samik: That's indeed that case. But when I was writing these comments the name was not decided on. We now have the name, the specification and the tools (a validating GLSL compiler that may emit SPIR-V, a Clang backend emitting SPIR-V (for OpenCL)).

Answer (score 0):

You can download mesa and build with passing the `-Dwith_tools=[glsl]` to generate `glsl_compiler`.